# Редирект в htaccess с .php на ссылки без него

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

Столкнулся с проблемой в настройке редиректов. Необходимо на сайте со старых ссылок, которые заканчивались расширением .php сделать редиректы на такие же ссылки, но без расширения. Нашел решение, все работает. Но сайт на WP, и данное правило в htaccess затрагивает и админку, а там это расширение нужно. Может кто-нибудь подскажет, каким образом можно исключить админку из правила? Заранее спасибо!

```
# RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# RewriteRule ^(.*)\.php$ $1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: ну вы почитали сами-то про `RewriteCond`?

Comment: В админке разве не к реальным файлам идет обращение? Если к ним, то строка условия `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` не должна давать добро на срабатывание редиректа.